# Skipping GRUB Menu?

Tags: grub2

I am brand-spanking new to this, so please bear with me. I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04

I waited for the file to download. When my computer restarted, it gave me an option to choose between Windows Vista, and Ubuntu.

When I click on Ubuntu, it brings me to a menu that talks about GRUB? I pressed TAB as I was instructed and it gave me a list of commands. I did not know what to do, and I cannot do anything else from there, except input the commands I was given, but I do not know what any of these commands actually do. I cannot use my computer from that state, I have to reset it ad go through the process all over again.

Please help! I don't know what to do. Thank you in advance!

Comment: sounds like grub is unable to see the root device.

Comment: Is this a Wubi install? If you get Windows Ubuntu choice first that would be from the Windows boot loader and then you get the grub menu? Just press enter. All the other commands are if you have boot issues.

Comment: Yes, it is a Wubi install. Yes, I get to first choose which operating system to choose, then it brings me to the "grub" menu. I tried pressing enter, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a grub prompt, try this:

`search -f /vmlinuz`

which should give you the link where the kernel is. You will get something like *hd0,1*

and then use that in the following command to start (assuming here that the root file system is in sda1),

```
grub> linux (hd0,1)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd (hd0,1)/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

Once booted you may have to reinstall grub using,

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: I'll try that, thanks I'll let you know what happens.